# How to make Jenkins check if file exists before archiving?

Tags: file, jenkins, attachment

I have a job (not a pipeline) in Jenkins which does some verification and generate a file, archive it and send by e-mail (using editable e-mail notification). If everything goes fine, it should not generate a file.

So the problem is when there no file is generated, because Jenkins faces it as an error and cancel the job. The workaround I'm using is to generate an empty file, but the guy who receives those e-mails is complaining about receiving e-mails with empty files.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Conditional Build Step Plugin [Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).
For example of how to use the plugin please check here [Usr case of the plugin](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/control-jenkins-steps-with-conditional-buildstep-plugin/)
[image]

Let me know if it worked

Comment: Good plugin, I didn't tried it first, thanks. Unfortunatelly archiving artefacts and e-mails are under "post-build acts".

Answer (score 0):

You can set archive artifacts to ignore the fact that there is nothing to archive.
Then your job will continue even if there is not file.